# AI cars should follow both player and other AI cars in UNITY

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a game in unity. The theme of this game is, there is a Arena in which few AI cars and a player car placed. Cars will collide to each other. in each collision car lose its health, if health become zero it will be drop out form the arena. If player successfully destroy all the cars. He will be moved to next level.
Now problem i am facing is, AI cars have default setting of `chase player` or `follow waypoints`. i want AI cars to follow both Players and other AI cars. how can i achieve this behaviour. I am using `Realistic Car Controller`.

Comment: I don't know this asset, but can't you set the target (player/waypoints) prefab ? Logically the difference between the two types is static (waypoint) or moving (player). Probably for optimization. Can't you set the setting to "chase player", and set an AI car as player ? Sorry if I'm talking shit, this is a freestyle comment.

Comment: i have tried this but it didn't work very well.

Comment: Show some code. I'm not a druid.

Comment: please read the documentation of RCC car controller.

Comment: its built-in behaviour

Comment: Since Realistic Car Controller is a paid asset, I strongly recommend you to contact them directly:
http://www.bonecrackergames.com/contact/

Comment: I checked the offical doc but didn't find where they talk about following a player... But seing how they manage waypoints, you should be able to manager them at runtime with your own logic script.